# Como codificar json com múltiplos objetos em PHP

Tags: php, json, foreach

Preciso do seguinte resultado:

```
{
    "sala": [{
        "horario": "18:30",
        "data": "Seg e Terça"
    }, {
        "horario": "10:30",
        "data": "Quarta Terça"
    }]
}
```

> > UPDATE

Estou fazendo assim em PHP:

```
                 /*criando objeto vazio*/
                $object = new stdClass();
                /*passando array para o objeto vazio*/
                $object->salas = array();

                $quantidade= $_POST['quantidade'];//imagina que aqui tem 2
           for($i=0;$i<count($quantidade);$i++){ //aqui vai rodar 2x

                $horario = $_POST['horarios_'.$quantidade]; //ATUALIZAÇÃO
                $dias= $_POST['dias_'.$quantidade]; //ATUALIZAÇÃO

                /*percorrendo o objeto vazio*/  
                foreach ($object as $key => $value) {           
                    $object_data = new stdClass();
                    $object_data->horario = $horario;//valor da hora
                    $object_data->data = $dias;//valor do dia
                    array_push($object->salas, $object_data);
                }

                /*codificando json*/    
                echo json_encode($object);

           }
```

Mas estou obtendo erradamente:

```
{
    "salas": [{
        "horario": ["18:30", "10:30"],
        "data": ["Seg e Terça, Quarta Terça"]
    }]
}
```

Depois que conseguir gerar a estrutura correta, como posso imprimir as informações de acordo com cada **horario** e **data**

Comment: Não é nada desculpe acho que já percebi, desculpe

Comment: Ok. Dar para ajudar?

Comment: Testei no ideone e funcionou confere la [https://ideone.com/j1qgjT](https://ideone.com/j1qgjT)

Comment: Certo, mas quando há mais de um valor para inserir em  `$object_data->horario` e `$object_data->data`, dar esse último json da pergunta, acho que é por conta do foreach que o envolve, como resolver?

Comment: Como tem os dados originalmente?

Comment: limpa a variável $object_data no final do foreach. unset($object_data)

Comment: @Euler01 acho que nao seja esse o problema, por que no inicio do foreach ja tem `$object_data = new stdClass();` entao já começa limpo certo?. @Lollipop posta como esta o array de "fora".

Comment: Pessoal, atualizei e coloquei o `for` para melhor entenderem e o `POST` que dar o valor as variáveis.

Comment: @NeuberOliveira já tive um problema semelhante a este, que resolvi limpando a variável. Desde então eu testo tudo. kkkkk

Comment: @Euler01, nada ainda :(

Answer (score 1):

O problema era que as variáveis `$horario` e `$dias` estavam passando um array, por isso quando havia mais de um laço no `for` ele criava um `[]` no `json` então eu determinei o índice `[0]` e funcionou.